# how to get file's extension from uri api 34

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my app I need to read a file.
I use:

```
 val launch = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
        it?.let {
            val checkFile = File(it.path!!)
   
            if (checkFile.extension == "db") {
                coroutine.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    profileVM.load(it, context)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I use android api 34 I can't to recivied an extention of file and check up it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if I use android api 34 I can't to recivied an extention of file and check up it.

If you mean by parsing the path portion of the `Uri`, that has never reliably worked. On modern versions of Android, that `Uri` will generally have a `content` scheme, and the path can be any random sequence of characters, such as `/questions/77787148/how-to-get-files-extension-from-uri-api-34`.

There is no requirement for the user to select a piece of content that has a file extension. It is 2024; relying on file extensions has been obsolete for a a decade or two.

You are welcome to use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(it).getName()`. This will return a "display name" of the document that the user should recognize. Sometimes, the "display name" will be a traditional filename, and you could see if it ends in your desired extension. But, again, there is no requirement for the "display name" to be a filename or for the user-chosen file to have any particular extension.

A better solution is to check to see if the content matches expectations in terms of data format, and gracefully degrade if the contents do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can with content resolver query() the obtained uri -not path part- for DISPLAY_NAME.